# Updating 50 UILabels at once is fast on the simulator but a turtle on iPod touch

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch

Not sure what to do other than core graphics.  UILabels update fine in simulator but more than 8 UILabels to update and it is getting slow.  Not sure if there is something I maybe missing to speed it up?  Otherwise I have to subclass a UIView do graphics there.

I have an NSTimer calling this, but it is the completion of the loop below that takes time.
If I remove the updating of the UILabels:(setBackgroundColor and setText) it runs normal speed. Also I originally used `viewWithTag` but in debugging this turtle problem, I switch to the array of UILabels to reduce overhead... no change in time though.  And the app doesn't work with any server, just stand-alone.

```
double r,g,b;
static int k=0;
int v;

for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
    r = arc4random() % 256;
    g = arc4random() % 256;
    b = arc4random() % 256;
    v = arc4random() % 2;
    [lblThinking[j] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:r/256 green:g/256 blue:b/256 alpha:1.0]];
    [lblThinking[j] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", v + 48]];//48  /65
}
k++;
```

Comment: this sounds like a job for Xcode's Instruments!

Comment: Post the code you are using to update the labels. Are you pulling data from the internet? Are you iterating through a ton of data? These are just some points that you should cover in your question.

Comment: WrightCS is correct. I'm not sure if its a problem with the code or if it's just a difference between the simulator and the iPod, but I suspect that if you are loading data from a URL, the access to the URL might be faster on the simulator because of more memory and a faster connection.

Comment: You can't compare performance on the simulator with that on the device. The simulator has your mac's processor, so it does everything much faster. Instruments is the way to go.

Comment: How do you use "Instruments"?

Comment: This seems quite strange. Refreshing 50 labels should be an easy task for iOS. I don't know iPod Touch performances (I use an iPhone) but reaching a refresh limit after just 8 labels is too early even with the older model. Are you using standard UILabel or sub-classes that use drawRect or that contain many subViews? Also, are these labels separated or they overlap? finally, what is your NSTimer periodicity? are you using Instruments' Time Profiler?

Comment: In Xcode set your iPod as the run device and press "command - I"

Comment: Well... after analyzing (THANK YOU for pointing out Instruments") and finding nothing to be a problem, I subclassed UIView and drew my changing boxes in their. It is faster than using UILabel but nothing like how fast the "simulator" runs.